# To send mail Embedded with image in Lambda function using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, lambda, nodemailer

I have created lambda function in AWS which send mail to various recipients.
I need to add company logo/banner at bottom of the mail.
Below is the code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'xxxxxx.xxxx.com',
port:587,
secure : true
});
var text = 'xxxxxxxxxx <img src="/Images/banner.jpg"  width="800px" width="78%" height="100px" 
height="11%" border="0" alt="Email banner">';
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'donotreplyhere@xxxx.com',
    to: 'skumar@xxx.com',
    subject: 'Test subject',
    html: text
};
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
if (error) {
    console.log("Error " +error);
   }   else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
     }
    });

 });
}
```

I am receiving the mail but image is not being displayed getting error : The linked image can't be displayed.

I also tried with s3 url by uploading images in s3 bucket but using its url like

```
<img src="https://falcon-bucket-us-east-1-xxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/dev/Images/banner.jpg"  
 width="800px" width="78%" height="100px" "height="11%" border="0" alt="Email banner">';
```

But this didn't worked, may be because its not public and i can't make it public.

Any other way that i can use to accomplish this task.

Thank for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the options:

- If you can use `CloudFront` in-front of S3 and use the CloudFront URL for the static content, do so. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) is more information.
- You can also host the static content on any publicly accessible website e.g. on [Github pages](https://pages.github.com) which is also a CDN for free.
- You can use [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) in place of the images. You must convert the images to the Base64 encoded version and use them directly in the HTML.
- You can use [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) as an image. You must convert your existing images to SVG and directly embed the contents in the HTML.

Comment: I used Base64 encoded image. Worked for me.